# Mongo not connecting on OS X after restart

Tags: macos, mongodb

I'm having trouble troubleshooting this. I was working on my node/express/mongodb app. I startup the app through the shell with mongod first, then Mongo, then Node. All has been well. Then I had an unexpected power down/restart and I haven't been able to connect. The first time I could not connect to mongod I used

```
brew services start mongodb
```

That started up mongod, but then when I connected to Mongo, I could not find my database. Here are the errors I am getting now (I did not log them before):

```
Symmetries:~ kioskuser$ mongod --dbpath statserver/data
2016-05-22T20:44:40.679-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=372 port=27017 dbpath=statserver/data 64-bit host=Symmetries.local
2016-05-22T20:44:40.691-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.3
2016-05-22T20:44:40.691-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-22T20:44:40.692-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "statserver/data" } }
2016-05-22T20:44:41.056-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in statserver/data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-05-22T20:44:41.057-0700 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - statserver/data/mongod.lock is not empty.
2016-05-22T20:44:41.057-0700 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2016-05-22T20:44:41.057-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2016-05-22T20:44:55.974-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-05-22T20:44:55.974-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2016-05-22T20:44:55.976-0700 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2016-05-22T20:44:55.976-0700 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'statserver/data/diagnostic.data'
2016-05-22T20:44:56.051-0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-05-22T20:44:56.137-0700 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK
```

Mongo doesn't give me any errors, but I should have a database called statserver with a collection called questions. I get this:

```
> show dbs
local  0.000GB
> use statserver
switched to db statserver
> show collections
>
```